# How do I add additional mod_rewrite rules on a wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have uploaded a file 'events.php' to my wordpress site (the wordpress is installed in my root directory).

I would like to make a mod_rewrite to this file so that one may go to mydomain.com/events

I tried simply doing something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule %events$ events.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Which didn't work.

I also found I could add rewrite tags via wordpress using its inbuilt functions like so:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^events?','/events.php','top');
```

This also didn't work - I simply end up on my default 404 page as though its reached a non-existent page within my wordpress.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I want events to go to events.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I’m wrong, but if all you want is for someone who goes to example.com/events to be directed to example.com/events.php, than you can just do a redirect like so.

Redirect 301 /events http://www.example.com/events.php

Comment: This would probably work, however directing events to events.php is not all I want to do. I will be sending more variables and will have a more complex url structure ie /events/13/3 as a way of sending an event id and a time id. Which would translate to something like events.php?event_id=13&time_id=3. I'm sure I could do a redirect also, but I'm looking for a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^events /events.php [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The directive that you had set for the URL would not match:

```
RewriteRule %events$ events.php [L]
```

Also, the directive is now below the condition that checks for an existing file, so that it never matches a direct request for events.php.